# find a regular expression and FA that each define $L_1 \cap L_2$

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to find a `regular expression` and `finite automaton` that each define $L_1 \cap L_2$, where $L_1 = (ab^*)^*$ and $L_2 = b(a+b)^*$.

How would I start doing this problem?

So I would draw a FA and when I draw it I would have a complement meaning take anywhere you have a plus, get rid of it and anywhere you didn't have a plus add one in. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by wanting to produce an automaton and then its complement. You're supposed to be taking the intersection, which is a different construction.

Comment: crosspost with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695575/find-a-regular-expression-and-fa-that-each-define-l1-l2

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Every non-empty string in $L_1$ starts with $a$. Every string in $L_2$ starts with $b$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Go back and re-read the material in your textbook on regular languages, regular expressions, and finite automata.  You might look especially closely at the material on closure properties of regular languages, on computing the intersection of regular languages, on the product construction, and on converting regexps to finite automata.  This is a standard textbook exercise that you should be able to solve easily if you understand those topics (and those topics should be covered in any good textbook on finite automata).

Comment: This is, of course, excellent advice, since coming to a good understanding of the topic is much more important than being able to answer this one question. But it's also overkill for the intersection of the two specific languages in the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, absolutely!  But if the person needs to ask us this question... then they probably would benefit from knowing how to solve this kind of question in general, not just in this specific (trivial) instance.  Based upon the question "How would I start doing this problem?", I am making the perhaps incorrect assumption that the person wants to learn about how to answer this kind of question in general rather than just wanting someone to solve his exercise for him.

Comment: I hope that's the correct assumption, too!